# Is there an SEO reason why I shouldn't redirect the root domain to a subdomain?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, subdomain

Is there any downside to redirecting the root domain and the www subdomain to a subdomain of my choice?

For example, redirecting `smith.com` and `www.smith.com` to `john.smith.com`.

I was talking to someone who works in SEO about doing this and they said that I would lose page authority - but I can't beleive that would be true as long as I implemented it properly with a 301 (permanent) redirect. Then again, when I googled it I found [an answer here on webmasters where someone commented a similar thing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61297/61802) (though it hasn't been given any positive or negative votes).

Comment: It's not an SEO reason, but subdomains are harder for usability because they are more to type.

Comment: That is a good point @StephenOstermiller , thank you. However, in this case that might not be true. The domain we're looking at buying is a persons full name, i.e. `firstnamelastname.com`. What I'm considering doing is buying `lastname.com` and creating a subdomain with their `firstname` so their website would be `firstname.lastname.com`. (So we're looking at an increase of 1 character, but if they attempted to go to `lastname.com` they would be redirected to `firstname.lastname.com`, so in that case we'd be saving 10 characters.)

Comment: Unless the name is extremely long, I would not do this. Even then I would rather choose another domain name than redirect to a sub-domain. If the name is manageable, such as josephschwartz then in would go with a single domain name and not complicate things unnecessary.

Comment: Have you considered dividing names into folders? example: http://example.com/lastname/firstname

Comment: Another thought is that sub-domains borrow most all trust metrics from the parent domain since it is only the domain that can aquire these metrics. If the parent domain is not building trust, then the sub-domain cannot gain more trust value from the parent and therefore can only perform in as much as it can without building trust. This is not the entire story. Some trust can be built by the sub-domain, however, it will not reach the same potential as if you used the parent domain. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc - your first comment doesn't really offer any reasonings, just opinion - do you have reasons you can articulate? With regards to your second comment I guess that is what the person I was speaking to was alluding to, can you share any resources that explain this - it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Your right. My first comment is opinion. But opinion based upon years and years of experience creating site after site. As for the second comment, I could explain this in detail, but am not around enough to type an answer. It is a damned busy week here. All day everyday day. Basically I am saying that an empty parent domain will somewhat limit what a sub-domain can do, however the degree to which is up to debate. I will try and carve out time later. I have people in my house waiting for me to finish an apartment. So I am cramming weeks of work into just one week. This one. Sorry. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent [article](http://seoabout.com/how-root-domain-subdomain-vs-subdirectory-affect-seo/) explaining how domains and subdomains impact SEO.  To summarize, subdomains have a relative dependence, not absolute, on the root domain. Bad SEO on a subdomain can negatively impact your root domain. Better to use subdirectories like www.mysite.com/blog than subdomains like blog.mysite.com so that all downstream pages can benefit from the keyword placement on your root domain.  Keyword placement feeds down, not up. Subdirectories receive and pass page rank and link "juice", so benefits flow both ways. However, do not go crazy with subdirectories or you will dilute the benefits.

Comment: Thank you for sharing - I will make the time to read it in detail soon. However, I think a distinction between what most articles discuss and what I will be doing is that they are talking about subdomain vs subdirectory, where as I am talking about forcing the subdomain in all cases. The whole website would essentially be hosted on this subdomain. The subdomain couldn't damage the root domain, because there is nothing there to be damaged, they will for all intents and purposes be one in the same thing.

Comment: Then you should be fine SEO wise.  As long as your "primary" domain is xxx.mysite.com and you do not use any SEO directed at mysite.com then there should be no interference.